# What would be the best way to save api data collected with python?

Tags: python, package

Ive been using python to print live api data in terminal. new data refreshes every 1-2 seconds using while=True and repeating. It would be good to be able to save this data somehow. are there any packages that could store the outputs of the function or the print outs and save them? preferably something simple as Im a beginner to python.

update: Im looking to do this for the purpose of statistical analysis, while im new to python, i have done R for 2 semesters.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Questions that ask about the 'best, worst, most useful, etc' should be red flags when crafting a question. If any answer could _technically_ be correct because it's 'their opinion', take a step back and possibly rethink your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply write the output to a text file

```
file = open("newfile.txt", "a")
for x in data:
    file.write(x)
```

The "a" option specifies that data will be appended to the bottom of the file.

Ideally though, you should look into creating a database. MySQL is probably the best for beginners because there's so much learning material on there internets. Keep in mind for future posts that stack overflow kind of looks down on really simple questions like this, but I've been where you are so I wanted to help.

Comment: Hi, he is suggesting you store the api response in a variable called `data`. and `for x in data:` means for item in the variable. In this case it would be a line in your API response. So you're writing the data line by line. However, depending on what you're looking to do with the response later, a small MySQL DB might be the way to go here